# Websocket connection is working but how do i send message and test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, websocket

Hello my websocket project is working but where can i send the message and test it?

Server Program.cs :

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Map("/", async httpContext =>
{
    if (httpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest is false)
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

    else
    {
        using var webSocket = await httpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();

        while (true)
        {
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Data {DateTime.Now}");
            await webSocket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, false, CancellationToken.None);
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
    }
});


app.UseWebSockets();
app.Run();
```

Client Program.cs :

```
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;

using var webSockets = new ClientWebSocket();

await webSockets.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://localhost:7163"), CancellationToken.None);

var buffer = new byte[256];

while (webSockets.State == WebSocketState.Open)
{
    var result = await webSockets.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
        await webSockets.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Bağlantı Kesildi", CancellationToken.None);

    else
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count));
}
```

[image]

I didn't know where to send the message somehow.

Websocket project is working.  Where can i send the message and test it?

Comment: Thank you. It's worked for me. But how can I send messages to specific clients and not to clients that are connecting. For example, I want to select one of the connecting clients and send it only to it.

Comment: You can send messages according to the id of the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is not complete. If you want to implement the function of sending and receiving information through WebSocket, please refer to the following steps:

1. Create a C# console program (I use a console program based on .Net FrameWork), install the Fleck nuget package, the code is as follows:

   ```
   namespace WebSocketConsole
   {
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
            var allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
            var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:7080");
            server.Start(socket =>
            {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The client connection is successful!");
                    allSockets.Add(socket);
                    Console.WriteLine("The current number of clients: " + allSockets.ToList().Count);
                };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The client is closed!");
                    allSockets.Remove(socket);
                    Console.WriteLine("The current number of clients: " + allSockets.ToList().Count);
                };
                // When a message is received
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
                };
            });

            // read input message
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            //When the message is not "exit", enter an infinite loop
            while (input != "exit")
            {
                //Traverse all socket clients and send messages to each client
                foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
                {
                    socket.Send(input);
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   }
2. Create a C# Asp.Net Web empty program, add an html file in it, and the code of the html file is as follows:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div>Send message:</div>
    <input type="text" id="msgContent" />
    <input type="button" value="Click me to send" onclick="CHAT.chat()" />
    <div>Accept message:</div>
    <div id="receiveMsg" style="background-color: gainsboro;"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript">

        window.CHAT = {
            socket: null,
            init: function() {
                if (window. WebSocket) {
                    CHAT.socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7080/ws");//websocket server address and port
                    CHAT.socket.onopen = function() {
                        console.log("Connection established successfully...");
                    },
                    CHAT.socket.onclose = function() {
                        console.log("Connection closed...");
                    },
                    CHAT.socket.onerror = function() {
                        console.log("An error occurred...");
                    },
                    CHAT.socket.onmessage = function(e) {
                        console.log("Received message: " + e.data);
                        var receiveMsg = document. getElementById("receiveMsg");
                        var html = receiveMsg. innerHTML;
                        receiveMsg.innerHTML = html + "<br/>" + e.data;
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("The browser does not support the websocket protocol...");
                }
            },
            chat: function() {
                var msg = document. getElementById("msgContent");
                CHAT.socket.send(msg.value);
            }
        };

        CHAT.init();

    </script>
   ```
3. Start the C# console program.
4. Right-click View in Browser in the html file of the Asp.Net Web empty program

[image]

5. After opening the page, enter the information you want to send, and click Send. At this time, you will find that the console program has received the information

[image]

[image]

[image]